# How to do NOT AUTH in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-blade

I am currently using `@auth('brand')` when showing the navigation bar, and if not auth, hide the navigation bar and show the login button. This is what I have so far:

```
@auth('brand')
 //show navigations
@endauth
if not auth
  Button Login
end not auth
```

**TRIED**

```
if(!@auth('brand'))
 //show navigations
@endif
//but this is not working, it's showing the nav bar and the log in button
```

Does anyone has ideas on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most blade directives can make use of the `@else` directive.

```
@auth('brand')
    //show navigations
@else
    // Show login
@endauth
```

This is because in the generated php code, the `@auth()` directive is compiled to an if structure that checks the authentication status.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this

```
@auth('brand')
    // The user is authenticated...
@endauth

@guest('brand')
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```

The @auth and @guest directives may be used to quickly determine if the current user is authenticated or is a guest:

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
@if( !auth()->guard('brand')->check() )
   //show navigations
@endif
```